# How to preserve the selection order of a pickerInput if multiple selections are allowed?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, pickerinput

Let's take my code as an example. If I use `selectInput` option where I can pick multiple choices, the first choice that I picked would be listed first, second choice would be listed second, etc.

However, if I use `pickerInput` option where I would pick multiple choices, no matter the order in which I pick the choice, whatever is listed first in the dropdown would be listed first instead. Is there a way for the `pickerInput` to emulate something similar to what `selectInput` does?

As an example, if I happened to pick Name 1 first and then Name 3 second, both `selectInput` and `pickerInput` would give me an output of `Sunday;Tuesday`.

However, if I pick Name 3 first and then Name 1 second, `selectInput` would give `Tuesday;Sunday`, but pickerInput would give `Sunday;Tuesday`.

How do I make sure `pickerInput` ordered the output similar to `selectInput`?

Code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

choices_df = data.frame(
  names = c('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'),
  id = c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday")#seq(3)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    selectInput(
      "input",
      h5("The output should give the choice name instead of its value"),
      choices= setNames(choices_df$id,choices_df$names),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    textOutput("output"),
    pickerInput(
      "input2",
      h5("The output should give the choice name instead of its value"),
      choices= setNames(choices_df$id,choices_df$names),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    textOutput("output2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #output$output <- renderPrint({paste(choices_df$names[choices_df$id==input$input])})  
  output$output <- renderPrint({paste(input$input, collapse = ";")}) 
  output$output2 <- renderPrint({paste(input$input2, collapse = ";")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do it with `pickerInput`? At the moment, it's not possible since pickerInput uses the bootstrap-select library which doesn't include that flexibility. See [here](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/585).

One solution without pickerInput is to use the `virtualSelectInput`.

```
virtualSelectInput(
      "input2",
      h5("The output should give the choice name instead of its value"),
      choices = prepare_choices(choices_df, names, id),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following `JS` in order to retain the selection order of a `pickerInput()` similar to the behaviour of a `selectInput()`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#input2').on('change.bs.select loaded.bs.select',
        function(event) {
            $(this).find('option:selected').prependTo(this);
        });
});
```

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- HTML(
    "
$(function(){
    $('#input2').on('change.bs.select loaded.bs.select',
        function(event) {
            $(this).find('option:selected').prependTo(this);
        });
});
"
)

choices_df = data.frame(
    names = c('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'),
    id = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday")#seq(3)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(js)),
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
        selectInput(
            "input",
            h5(
                "selectInput: The output should give the choice name instead of its value"
            ),
            choices = setNames(choices_df$id, choices_df$names),
            multiple = TRUE
        ),
        textOutput("output"),
        pickerInput(
            "input2",
            h5(
                "pickerInput: The output should give the choice name instead of its value"
            ),
            choices = setNames(choices_df$id, choices_df$names),
            multiple = TRUE
        ),
        textOutput("output2")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    #output$output <- renderPrint({paste(choices_df$names[choices_df$id==input$input])})
    output$output <-
        renderPrint({
            paste(input$input, collapse = ";")
        })
    output$output2 <-
        renderPrint({
            paste(input$input2, collapse = ";")
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```